# Adjust Namespaces equivalent for CodeRush

Tags: coderush

Resharper has [Adjust Namespaces](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Adjust_Namespaces.html) which allows you to correct the namespaces of all files in a folder, project, or solution.

Is there a feature or plugin available for CodeRush/Refactor that is comparible to Resharper's Adjust Namespaces feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built in equivalent feature at the current time.

However there is a rich ecosystem of plugins for CodeRush, which includes [CR_SyncNamespacesToFolder](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/CR_SyncNamespacesToFolder)

This would seem to provider the feature you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see this on the community plugin site. I should have looked in the Wiki.

Comment: Off the top of my head there should be 2 Refactorings with this plugin. 'Synchronize to Folder Name' will only affect the current file. However 'Synchronize to Folder Names' should affect all files in the active project.